# Getting Firebase Snapshot as array and set to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to return the results of a Firebase snapshot as an array so that I can `ng-repeat` through them (by default it returned objects) The last line is where I try to set the objects in an array and set them to a scope to repeat through. But I seem to be confused on the basic concept of setting the value to the array :/ Any help would be great.

```
const businessKey = '-KQ1hFH0qrvKSrymmn9d';
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');


function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    discoverRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
        let businesRef = businessRef.child(snap.key);
        businesRef.once('value', cb);
    });
}

getDiscoverBarContent(businessKey, snap => {
    snap.forEach((child) => {
         var item = {};
         item._key = snap.val();
         array.push(item);
         /*$scope.discover = array*/
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the other answers could have worked, but I really didn't want to destroy what I had in order to Use another method. Here is the code I used to solve this issue:

```
$scope.discover = [];
const businessKey = $scope.finalItem.$id;
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');


function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    discoverRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
        let businesRef = businessRef.child(snap.key);
        businesRef.once('value', cb);
    });
}

getDiscoverBarContent(businessKey, snap => {
    var snapVal = snap.val();
    $scope.discover.push(snapVal);
});
```

First, for the sake of preventing errors, we added the top `$scope.discover = []`.
Second, I couldn't `forEach` through a Firebase Object. Instead I needed to set the `snap.val()` to a variable and push that into my `$scope.discover`. The data can now be repeated through via `ng-repeat="place in discover track by $index"` as expected. Thanks for the other advice, but this worked better for my current code. I will definitely keep the other advice in mind though if starting over.

Answer (score 0):

Try [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire).

Angularfire is a convenient helper for firebase providing you a few useful tools for building angular apps. it includes 3 main services. simply inject the one(s) you need in each controller. make sure firebase is already initialized first:

`$firebaseAuth` 
`$firebaseObject`
`$firebaseArray`

Here is how you use `$firebaseArray`:

```
const businessKey = '-KQ1hFH0qrvKSrymmn9d';
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');


function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    let myArray = $firebaseArray(discoverRef.child(key));
    myArray.$loaded().then(() => { cb(a) });
}

getDiscoverBarContent(businessKey, data => {
    // ctrl.property = data
    // $scope.property = data;
});
```

If i got any syntax wrong, i'm sorry. I still use the classic JS syntax, none of this es5/es6 whatever the hell its called.

Documentation for angularfire: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md

Unrelated, but if you need to paginate easily in angular, save yourself the trouble and use the following library: https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-paginator